# Vue: Why my html table columns are appearing as single straight line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, html-table

I have an array which consist of 3 other arrays. Each array is a column of a table. But all the rows are appearing in a single straight line.

[image]

I am using v-for here and looking into some exactly similar examples in the internet, however I am not able to fix it in Vue.

```js
< script >
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      table: [
        ["Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass"],
        ["Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail"],
        ["NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
< /script >
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">A</th>
                    <th scope="col">B</th>
                    <th scope="col">C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, i) in table" :key="i">
                     <td scope="row" v-for="(col, i) in row" :key="'A' + i">{{ col }} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

I really do not have any idea why this is happening.

**UPDATE: Nested Objects Example for the same issue**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#main',
  data:
  {
   fptable: {"table": {"A": {0: "Pass", 1: "Pass", 2: "Pass", 3: "Pass", 4: "Pass", 5: "Pass"}, 
                               "B": {0: "Fail", 1: "Fail", 2: "Fail", 3: "Fail", 4: "Fail", 5: "Fail"}, 
                               "C": {0: "NA"  , 1: "NA"  , 2: "NA", 3: "NA"  , 4: "NA"  , 5: "NA"}}}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<template id="main">
<div>
<body class="container mt-8" id="data" v-if="!table === undefined || !table.length == 0">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" v-for="(values, key) in fptable['table']" :key="key">{{ key }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(values, key) in fptable['table']" :key="key">
                        <td v-for="(v, k) in values" :key="k">{{ values[k] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </body>
        
    </div>
</template>
```

Still the same problem as in picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a table with 3 columns you should code your template like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#main',
  data:
  {
    fptable: 
    {
      "FailPass-table": 
      {
        "A": {0: "Pass", 1: "Pass", 2: "Pass", 3: "Pass", 4: "Pass", 5: "Pass"}, 
        "B": {0: "Fail", 1: "Fail", 2: "Fail", 3: "Fail", 4: "Fail", 5: "Fail"}, 
        "C": {0: "NA"  , 1: "NA"  , 2: "NA", 3: "NA"  , 4: "NA"  , 5: "NA"}
      }
    }
  },
computed:
{
  tableData()
  {
    return this.transpose(Object.values(this.fptable['FailPass-table']).map(function(col)
    {
      return Object.values(col);
    }));
  },
  tableHeader()
  {
    return Object.keys(this.fptable['FailPass-table']);
  }
},
methods:
{
  transpose(arr)
  {
    return arr[0].map(function(col,i)
    {
      return arr.map(function(row)
      {
        return row[i];
      });
    });
  }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<template id="main">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="(col,idx) in tableHeader" :key="idx">{{ col }}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row,rowIndex) in tableData" :key="rowIndex">
                     <td v-for="(col,colIndex) in row" :key="colIndex">{{ col }} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my main.js file already has a vue instance. Is not it possible to solve without creating another instance. This particular code is a component which is registered into Home.vue. Entry point is main.js where the vue instance is.

Comment: This snippet is adopted to work on StackOverflow. Of course in your own project you will use a Single-File Component. The point is that your cycle goes through the table rows - while your data contains the table columns. So if you do not want to first transpose your data - you have to take into account this discrepancy.

Comment: at:IVO: Thanks for the update. It is working. However later I realized, the project that I am working on has actually another issue in making this table. Actually, I have objects inside objects and I have to iterate them dynamically everything. I mean header and the body as well. Not hard coded. As since I was trying to make this happen since three weeks, the table is displayed but again the same problem as you can see in the picture I posted in the description. if you would like to help in this issue that I have described here. Kindly let me know. I will update the necessary details here.

Comment: The question did not mention objects nested in other objects - only arrays nested into another array. But in both cases it will be easier for you if you first convert your nested structure into array of rows, and each row - to be array of columns (cells). Then you can easily use 2 V-FOR - one for the TR and one for the TD tags.

Comment: Hi IVO. I have updated the question. This time with nested objects

Comment: Hi IVO thanks a lot for thee answer. I tried the same solution without transposing and it was the same. But now everything is fixed. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning to the nested object solution. This is also how it can be solved.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#main',
  data:
  {
   data: {"table": {"A": {0: "Pass", 1: "Pass", 2: "Pass", 3: "Pass", 4: "Pass", 5: "Pass"}, 
                               "B": {0: "Fail", 1: "Fail", 2: "Fail", 3: "Fail", 4: "Fail", 5: "Fail"}, 
                               "C": {0: "NA"  , 1: "NA"  , 2: "NA", 3: "NA"  , 4: "NA"  , 5: "NA"}}},
   table: []
  },
  
  methods: {
        checkTable(){
            this.table = []

            for (let key in this.data["table"]) {
                this.table.push(Object.values(this.data["table"][key]));
            }
  
        }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<template id="main">
<div>
<body class="container mt-8" id="data" v-if="!table === undefined || !table.length == 0">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead >
          <tr>
              <th scope="col" v-for="(values, key) in data['table']" :key="key">{{ key }}</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           <tr v-for="(row,rowIndex) in table[0]" :key="rowIndex">
              <td v-for="(col,colIndex) in table" :key="colIndex">{{ table[colIndex][rowIndex] }} </td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <button @click="checkTable">View Table</button><br><br>
</body>
</div>
</template>
```